# What is the code for key "Volume UP" in Microsoft SendKeys Class

Tags: c#, .net

I need to send "Volume Up" key with SendKeys Class. But I don't know what is the code for that key.

There is a list with key-codes, but there is no info about "Volume Up" key:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.8

(And I'm also searching for "Volume Down" and "Volume Mute")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control Windows system volume using JScript or VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216334/how-to-control-windows-system-volume-using-jscript-or-vbscript)

Comment: Wrong class.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157609/keybd-event-along-with-postmessage-win32-not-working-when-visual-studio-has-focu

Comment: Thank you, but that links does not solve my issue. I'm using software IOTLink and I need to send that 'Volume UP' key to it (https://gitlab.com/iotlink/iotlink/-/wikis/Addons/Commands section "Send Keys")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the `SendKeys` class. The documentation is correct.

You can also [check the implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs,7f418f7116a99f50) to see what is supported.

For any code not contained in the allowed key list and not representing a single character, you will get an `ArgumentException`.

Use native Windows messages for sending that key to an application, as @HansPassant suggests in his comment. Here is his very helpful [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504831/2846483) how to do this.

You could also try third-party Windows input simulation solutions, like e.g. this open source [WindowsInput](https://github.com/MediatedCommunications/WindowsInput) library.