# Powershell Sendkeys [char] definitions

Tags: powershell, char, sendkeys

Answers have been given on using powershell to control Windows settings (such as speaker volume control) using the following method:

```
$obj = new-object -com wscript.shell 
$obj.SendKeys([char]173)
```

- Ref.1:
  [Change audio level from powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355891/change-audio-level-from-powershell)
- Ref.2:
  [How can I mute/unmute my sound from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255419/how-can-i-mute-unmute-my-sound-from-powershell)

However I cannot find any information on where those numbers (e.g. 173 above, or 174/175 in the link) are coming from how they are defined and what other number definitions are & can do.

Can you direct me to a listing of where those numbers are given as defined actions?  For example how would I know what 172 would do? or 200? etc?

Thanks, Lawrence

Comment: 173 is hyphen `-`. Just type `[char]number` in PowerShell terminal

Comment: @NekoMusume, Note that the OP isn't interested in what `[char] 173` means _on the PowerShell side_, but in the special meaning these characters have as  Windows _virtual-key codes_ (`173` == `0xAD` == `VK_VOLUME_MUTE`) when interpreted by the `.SendKeys()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though *technically*, from PowerShell's perspective, you're passing a specific Unicode character - with *code point* `173` == `0xAD` ==  SOFT HYPHEN, [`U+00AD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad) - **`.SendKeys()` seemingly interprets that character's code point (the underlying number) as a Windows *virtual-key code***, representing a *key on the keyboard*, namely the `VK_VOLUME_MUTE` key (`0xAD`) in this case.

The **list of all virtual-key codes** is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), though I'm unclear what subset of them are actually usable with `.SendKeys()`.

To recap the ones from the linked questions:

- `[char] 173` is `VK_VOLUME_MUTE`(`0xAD`)
- `[char] 174` is `VK_VOLUME_DOWN`(`0xAE`)
- `[char] 175` is `VK_VOLUME_UP`(`0xAF`)

As an aside: In *Windows PowerShell* (but no longer in PowerShell [Core] v6+) it seems that an additional cast to `[string]` is necessary; e.g. (mutes / unmutes the volume):

```bash
# Extra [string] cast is *not* necessary anymore in PowerShell [Core], v6+
(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys([string] [char] 173)
```

Comment: Great answer. For anyone trying to make this work with the next keys in the series, (VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK, VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK) it likely won't work. See here for an example to try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504831/162215