# What command to play next song in media-player?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, media-player

In Windows, there are multiple ways of playing songs on your computer; spotify, Windows Media Player, Foobar2000, Winamp etc etc. If you own a keyboard with media-keys, you can sometimes skip a song or play/pause it by pressing a button on that keyboard. The keyboard will say to windows to skip a song that is currently being played WHATEVER media-player is being used.

How can I pause/skip the current song that is being played in Windows without needing to know the media-player?

Languages; C# or nodejs, it all depends on how this is possible.

Comment: What scripting language?

Comment: Good one. Shouldn't really matter, but I prefer C# or nodejs (depends on the possible implementations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the answer here:**
[Simulate keyboard event if sender is not in focus and without knowing target window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743181/simulate-keyboard-event-if-sender-is-not-in-focus-and-without-knowing-target-win)

*Reference*
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275(v=vs.85).aspx

**Bad alternative:**
https://superuser.com/questions/278951/my-keyboard-has-no-media-keys-can-i-control-media-without-them